# How do you fix all of these py2exe problems?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, py2exe

I have been making a game with Python and Pygame, and I've FINALLY finished it! It has a main.py, and this uses 2 other .py files: process.py and classes.py. I have been trying to make it into a standalone .exe (using this setup.py: http://www.pygame.org/wiki/Pygame2exe) but have encountered several difficulties. I used Python 2.6 before, but that gave me two errors. I have just tried 2.7, but I encountered these errors:

```
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\dist\setup.exe\zipextimporter.py:82: RuntimeWarning: import display: No module named _view
(ImportError: No module named _view)
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\dist\setup.exe\zipextimporter.py:82: RuntimeWarning: import draw: No module named _view
(ImportError: No module named _view)
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\dist\setup.exe\zipextimporter.py:82: RuntimeWarning: import image: No module named _view
(ImportError: No module named _view)
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\dist\setup.exe\zipextimporter.py:82: RuntimeWarning: import pixelcopy: No module named _view
(ImportError: No module named _view)
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\dist\setup.exe\zipextimporter.py:82: RuntimeWarning: import transform: No module named _view
(ImportError: No module named _view)
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\dist\setup.exe\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'dist_dir'
error: invalid command 'bdist'
```

Can anyone help me? I need to fix ALL of these errors! The error that has always appeared is the 'dist_dir' error, and I cannot find a suitable solution for this! I have installed SetupTools for 2.7 and it still comes up, despite being told this would fix it. This is the error that I need to fix the most, so if you only have an appropriate solution for this, that is fine. Thank you!

Comment: How did you attempt to run your setup file?  You want `python.exe setup.py py2exe`.  The invalid command `bdist` suggests that you have extra command line arguments that are causing problems.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the last, "error: invalid command 'bdist'"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the first lines of errors add this to your code:

```
import pygame._view
```

The last line error is probably with your code.  Please post the complete code from your game.  Try the first fix and then see if the application runs.  Good luck!